# jQuery not responding for first paragraph hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am using jQuery in my blogger blog to split my content.
It works fine but it always shows the 1st paragraph of post on every page and its no hiding the 1st paragraph.

I have followed [this link](http://www.hackinguniversity.in/2015/05/split-blogger-post-add-pages.html) to include my jQuery.
And here is my [blog-post](http://fitnessandhealthtips-us.blogspot.com/2016/01/makeup-tips-that-will-save-your-time.html)

The "Tip:1" paragraph of my post is always shown while others are working as I want.
Please let me know the issue, If I am missing something.

EDITED:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script style="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.page1').click(function(){
jQuery('.content1').show();
jQuery('.content2').hide();
jQuery('.content3').hide();
jQuery('.content4').hide();
jQuery('.content5').hide();
jQuery('.content6').hide();
return false;
});
jQuery('.page2').click(function(){
jQuery('.content2').show();
jQuery('.content1').hide();
jQuery('.content3').hide();
jQuery('.content4').hide();
jQuery('.content5').hide();
jQuery('.content6').hide();
return false;
});
jQuery('.page3').click(function(){
jQuery('.content1').hide();
jQuery('.content2').hide();
jQuery('.content3').show();
jQuery('.content4').hide();
jQuery('.content5').hide();
jQuery('.content6').hide();
return false;
});
jQuery('.page4').click(function(){
jQuery('.content1').hide();
jQuery('.content2').hide();
jQuery('.content3').hide();
jQuery('.content4').show();
jQuery('.content5').hide();
jQuery('.content6').hide();
return false;
});
jQuery('.page5').click(function(){
jQuery('.content1').hide();
jQuery('.content2').hide();
jQuery('.content3').hide();
jQuery('.content4').hide();
jQuery('.content5').show();
jQuery('.content6').hide();
return false;
});
jQuery('.page6').click(function(){
jQuery('.content1').hide();
jQuery('.content2').hide();
jQuery('.content3').hide();
jQuery('.content4').hide();
jQuery('.content5').hide();
jQuery('.content6').show();
return false;
});
});
</script>


<span class="content1">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">There
are many girls who do not leave house without doing makeup on their face, even
if it is to go to the nearest shop, while there are also some girls who
consider the makeup like a waste of time.&nbsp;
However, for special occasions, such girls also make use of makeup to
look cuter!</span></div>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<br /></div>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Here in
this post I have mentioned some handy makeup tips which does not take your much
time.</span><br />
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;"><br /></span></div>
<h3 style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large; line-height: 115%;">&nbsp;Tip:1 Use Correction Fluid Properly</span></h3>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;"><br /></span></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CDkciSOhSDs/VogDeWeDBBI/AAAAAAAAADA/zb0N9yA5Pic/s1600/Make%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="makeup tips" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CDkciSOhSDs/VogDeWeDBBI/AAAAAAAAADA/zb0N9yA5Pic/s1600/Make%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" title="" /></a></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<br /></div>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-V2H0VE6kdwU/VogFWa8fXzI/AAAAAAAAADU/qeNNoVoF9Qo/s1600/eye%2Bmake%2Bup.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="correct eye makeup  vs incorrect eye makeup" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-V2H0VE6kdwU/VogFWa8fXzI/AAAAAAAAADU/qeNNoVoF9Qo/s1600/eye%2Bmake%2Bup.jpg" title="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<br /></div>
</span>

<span class="content2" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;">Tip:2 Comb Your Eyebrows</span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">If you
do not have enough time for a full makeup, comb your eyebrows simply, it can
dramatically change your look.</span><br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vLbbLkcppZM/VogF0m_NLgI/AAAAAAAAADc/q7AuFPN2MhQ/s1600/full%2Bmake%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="full makeup tips" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vLbbLkcppZM/VogF0m_NLgI/AAAAAAAAADc/q7AuFPN2MhQ/s1600/full%2Bmake%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" title="" /></a></div>
<br /></div>
</span>

<span class="content3" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;"><span style="line-height: 115%;">Tip:3&nbsp;</span><span style="line-height: 18.4px;">Use A Credit Card</span></span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use a
credit card or any other hard card to draw a straight line to trace the
"cat's eyes"</span><br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Md5EUwViUWE/VogGWTTYBCI/AAAAAAAAADk/7Z6q8XtlyK8/s1600/use%2Beyeliner.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="use credit card to draw straight line" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Md5EUwViUWE/VogGWTTYBCI/AAAAAAAAADk/7Z6q8XtlyK8/s1600/use%2Beyeliner.jpg" title="" /></a></div>
<br /></div>
</span>

<span class="content4" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-size: large;"><span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; line-height: 115%;">Tip:4&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: Georgia, serif; line-height: 18.4px;">Use Clear Pencil</span></span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use
clear pencil as a basis for intense color on your eyelids.</span><br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eQqNha7Ul4s/VogGh0bCddI/AAAAAAAAADs/nHFFmXfQtFo/s1600/base.jpeg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="base" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eQqNha7Ul4s/VogGh0bCddI/AAAAAAAAADs/nHFFmXfQtFo/s1600/base.jpeg" title="" /></a></div>
<br /></div>
</span>

<span class="content5" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large; line-height: 18.4px;">Tip:5 Paint Your Eyelashes Cleaner</span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use a
credit card or any other hard card to paint your eyelashes cleaner.</span><br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DuXSluThtqE/VogGqv0KHBI/AAAAAAAAAD0/JSy7bmMQm7Q/s1600/eyelashes%2Bcleaner.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="eyelashes cleaner" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DuXSluThtqE/VogGqv0KHBI/AAAAAAAAAD0/JSy7bmMQm7Q/s1600/eyelashes%2Bcleaner.jpg" title="" /></a></div>
<br /></div>
</span>

<span class="content6" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;"><span style="line-height: 115%;">Tip:6&nbsp;</span><span style="line-height: 18.4px;">Use Light Shade Pencil</span></span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use
light shade pencil to give more freshness and vigor to your eyes.</span><br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kb1lAlxKnfA/VogG7Nu43YI/AAAAAAAAAD8/tJmBrrpjFXA/s1600/eye%2Bpencil.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="eye pencil" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kb1lAlxKnfA/VogG7Nu43YI/AAAAAAAAAD8/tJmBrrpjFXA/s1600/eye%2Bpencil.jpg" title="" /></a></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<br /></div>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
If you like this post, don't forget to share these makeup tips with your friends!!!</div>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;"><br /></span></div>
</span>

<p><b>Pages: <span style="color: #3d85c6">
<a href="#" class="page1">1</a>
<a href="#" class="page2">2</a>
<a href="#" class="page3">3</a>
<a href="#" class="page4">4</a>
<a href="#" class="page5">5</a>
<a href="#" class="page6">6</a></span></b></p>
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is a working code sample in the source of his site, which he linked to.

Comment: code should be within the question

Comment: @MustafaGaziani is this result https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/Lzvgftbb/ is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Exactly, I was looking for this! But I want the first two paragraphs also be hidden when i go to page 2,3 and son only Tip:2 should be shown on page 2.

Comment: so this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/Lzvgftbb/1/ ??

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Exactly (Y) Thank you So much. But its not working in Blogger and all the way in IDE and JSfiddle. I have used your 1st JSfiddle file and its working in blogger as well!
Thank you for your great Help! Have made changes according to your 1st JSfiddle file

Comment: that's weird, it should either both work or both don't, I only moved the two paragraphs out then put them back in, ok let me try something

Comment: do you have control over the generated html? I mean can you insert a div?

Comment: Actually Yes! Its Strange. But what I think is Blogger doesn't allow to hide 1st paragraph. Either way both of your code are working properly when I am using IDE or JSfiddle.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/Lzvgftbb/2/, I wrapped the first two paragraphs in another div

Comment: Ok good then, something else as side note, I think it'd work better if you scroll the page up upon clicking on links, because it stays at bottom

Comment: yes exactly! But I don't know how to make it work if you have the CSS for this please share it with me.

Comment: it is javascript not CSS, I put it in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First shortening the code by adding `.contents` class to all section divs, and instead of this

```
jQuery('.content1').show();
jQuery('.content2').hide();
jQuery('.content3').hide();
jQuery('.content4').hide();
jQuery('.content5').hide();
jQuery('.content6').hide();
```

we just do it like:

```
jQuery('.contents').hide();
jQuery('.content1').show();
```

Then move the first two paragraph out of the first `.content1`, and wrap them in another div with same classes `contents` and `content1` to hide and show it same time as we show and hide the first section with "*Tip:1 Use Correction Fluid Properly*" title.

Also the page needs to scroll up every time it shows new section instead of staying at the end of the page we add this line `jQuery(window).scrollTop(0)` <sup>(*)</sup>, so now we have this code:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/kho0m1wj/)

***Full Code:***

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.page1').click(function() {
    jQuery('.contents').hide();
    jQuery('.content1').show();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
    return false;
  });
  jQuery('.page2').click(function() {
    jQuery('.contents').hide();
    jQuery('.content2').show();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
    return false;
  });
  jQuery('.page3').click(function() {
    jQuery('.contents').hide();
    jQuery('.content3').show();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
    return false;
  });
  jQuery('.page4').click(function() {
    jQuery('.contents').hide();
    jQuery('.content4').show();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
    return false;
  });
  jQuery('.page5').click(function() {
    jQuery('.contents').hide();
    jQuery('.content5').show();
    return false;
  });
  jQuery('.page6').click(function() {
    jQuery('.contents').hide();
    jQuery('.content6').show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content1 contents">
  <div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
    <span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">There
are many girls who do not leave house without doing makeup on their face, even
if it is to go to the nearest shop, while there are also some girls who
consider the makeup like a waste of time.&nbsp;
However, for special occasions, such girls also make use of makeup to
look cuter!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
    <span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Here in
this post I have mentioned some handy makeup tips which does not take your much
time.</span>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<span class="contents content1">
  <span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;"><br /></span>
<h3 style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large; line-height: 115%;">&nbsp;Tip:1 Use Correction Fluid Properly</span></h3>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
  <span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;"><br /></span>
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CDkciSOhSDs/VogDeWeDBBI/AAAAAAAAADA/zb0N9yA5Pic/s1600/Make%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
    <img alt="makeup tips" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CDkciSOhSDs/VogDeWeDBBI/AAAAAAAAADA/zb0N9yA5Pic/s1600/Make%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" title="" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <br />
</div>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
  <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-V2H0VE6kdwU/VogFWa8fXzI/AAAAAAAAADU/qeNNoVoF9Qo/s1600/eye%2Bmake%2Bup.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
      <img alt="correct eye makeup  vs incorrect eye makeup" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-V2H0VE6kdwU/VogFWa8fXzI/AAAAAAAAADU/qeNNoVoF9Qo/s1600/eye%2Bmake%2Bup.jpg" title="" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
  <br />
</div>
</span>

<span class="contents content2" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;">Tip:2 Comb Your Eyebrows</span>
</h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">If you
do not have enough time for a full makeup, comb your eyebrows simply, it can
dramatically change your look.</span>
<br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vLbbLkcppZM/VogF0m_NLgI/AAAAAAAAADc/q7AuFPN2MhQ/s1600/full%2Bmake%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
    <img alt="full makeup tips" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vLbbLkcppZM/VogF0m_NLgI/AAAAAAAAADc/q7AuFPN2MhQ/s1600/full%2Bmake%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" title="" />
  </a>
</div>
<br />
</div>
</span>

<span class="contents content3" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;"><span style="line-height: 115%;">Tip:3&nbsp;</span><span style="line-height: 18.4px;">Use A Credit Card</span></span>
</h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use a
credit card or any other hard card to draw a straight line to trace the
"cat's eyes"</span>
<br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Md5EUwViUWE/VogGWTTYBCI/AAAAAAAAADk/7Z6q8XtlyK8/s1600/use%2Beyeliner.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
    <img alt="use credit card to draw straight line" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Md5EUwViUWE/VogGWTTYBCI/AAAAAAAAADk/7Z6q8XtlyK8/s1600/use%2Beyeliner.jpg" title="" />
  </a>
</div>
<br />
</div>
</span>

<span class="contents content4" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-size: large;"><span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; line-height: 115%;">Tip:4&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: Georgia, serif; line-height: 18.4px;">Use Clear Pencil</span></span>
</h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use
clear pencil as a basis for intense color on your eyelids.</span>
<br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eQqNha7Ul4s/VogGh0bCddI/AAAAAAAAADs/nHFFmXfQtFo/s1600/base.jpeg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
    <img alt="base" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eQqNha7Ul4s/VogGh0bCddI/AAAAAAAAADs/nHFFmXfQtFo/s1600/base.jpeg" title="" />
  </a>
</div>
<br />
</div>
</span>

<span class="contents content5" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large; line-height: 18.4px;">Tip:5 Paint Your Eyelashes Cleaner</span>
</h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use a
credit card or any other hard card to paint your eyelashes cleaner.</span>
<br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DuXSluThtqE/VogGqv0KHBI/AAAAAAAAAD0/JSy7bmMQm7Q/s1600/eyelashes%2Bcleaner.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
    <img alt="eyelashes cleaner" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DuXSluThtqE/VogGqv0KHBI/AAAAAAAAAD0/JSy7bmMQm7Q/s1600/eyelashes%2Bcleaner.jpg" title="" />
  </a>
</div>
<br />
</div>
</span>

<span class="contents content6" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;"><span style="line-height: 115%;">Tip:6&nbsp;</span><span style="line-height: 18.4px;">Use Light Shade Pencil</span></span>
</h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use
light shade pencil to give more freshness and vigor to your eyes.</span>
<br />


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kb1lAlxKnfA/VogG7Nu43YI/AAAAAAAAAD8/tJmBrrpjFXA/s1600/eye%2Bpencil.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
    <img alt="eye pencil" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kb1lAlxKnfA/VogG7Nu43YI/AAAAAAAAAD8/tJmBrrpjFXA/s1600/eye%2Bpencil.jpg" title="" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <br />
</div>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  If you like this post, don't forget to share these makeup tips with your friends!!!</div>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;"><br /></span>
</div>
</span>

<p><b>Pages: <span style="color: #3d85c6">
<a href="#" class="page1">1</a>
<a href="#" class="page2">2</a>
<a href="#" class="page3">3</a>
<a href="#" class="page4">4</a>
<a href="#" class="page5">5</a>
<a href="#" class="page6">6</a></span></b>
</p>
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> *you have other numbers other than* `0` *if you don't want the page to scroll to the very top of the page.*

Comment: You welcome @MustafaGaziani, I'm glad it helped, enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

Can you add some code regarding the question.According to what i understood from above question i think you should hide the paragraph when document is ready.

Try this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Write your hiding code here.
})
```

Or you can simply add a class to the paragraph which hides the content when u navigate to new pages like -

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

You can refine the code as below- it will work fine since i verified in you blog.PLEASE VERIFY THE COMMENTS WHICH ARE IN CAPITAL LETTERS.

```
<div class="post-body entry-content" id="post-body-3211737812026835425">
<p class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

//YOUR HIDING LOGIC HERE

</p>

//CONTENT1 SHOULD COME OUT OF <P> TAG

<span class="content1" style="display: none;">

  <div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;">Tip:2 Comb Your Eyebrows</span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">If you
do not have enough time for a full makeup, comb your eyebrows simply, it can
dramatically change your look.</span><br>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vLbbLkcppZM/VogF0m_NLgI/AAAAAAAAADc/q7AuFPN2MhQ/s1600/full%2Bmake%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="full makeup tips" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vLbbLkcppZM/VogF0m_NLgI/AAAAAAAAADc/q7AuFPN2MhQ/s1600/full%2Bmake%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" title=""></a></div>
<br></div>
</span>

<span class="content2" style="display: inline;">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;">Tip:2 Comb Your Eyebrows</span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">If you
do not have enough time for a full makeup, comb your eyebrows simply, it can
dramatically change your look.</span><br>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vLbbLkcppZM/VogF0m_NLgI/AAAAAAAAADc/q7AuFPN2MhQ/s1600/full%2Bmake%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="full makeup tips" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vLbbLkcppZM/VogF0m_NLgI/AAAAAAAAADc/q7AuFPN2MhQ/s1600/full%2Bmake%2Bup%2Btips.jpg" title=""></a></div>
<br></div>
</span>

<span class="content3" style="display: none;">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;"><span style="line-height: 115%;">Tip:3&nbsp;</span><span style="line-height: 18.4px;">Use A Credit Card</span></span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use a
credit card or any other hard card to draw a straight line to trace the
"cat's eyes"</span><br>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Md5EUwViUWE/VogGWTTYBCI/AAAAAAAAADk/7Z6q8XtlyK8/s1600/use%2Beyeliner.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="use credit card to draw straight line" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Md5EUwViUWE/VogGWTTYBCI/AAAAAAAAADk/7Z6q8XtlyK8/s1600/use%2Beyeliner.jpg" title=""></a></div>
<br></div>
</span>

<span class="content4" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-size: large;"><span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; line-height: 115%;">Tip:4&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: Georgia, serif; line-height: 18.4px;">Use Clear Pencil</span></span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use
clear pencil as a basis for intense color on your eyelids.</span><br>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eQqNha7Ul4s/VogGh0bCddI/AAAAAAAAADs/nHFFmXfQtFo/s1600/base.jpeg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="base" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eQqNha7Ul4s/VogGh0bCddI/AAAAAAAAADs/nHFFmXfQtFo/s1600/base.jpeg" title=""></a></div>
<br></div>
</span>

<span class="content5" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large; line-height: 18.4px;">Tip:5 Paint Your Eyelashes Cleaner</span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use a
credit card or any other hard card to paint your eyelashes cleaner.</span><br>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DuXSluThtqE/VogGqv0KHBI/AAAAAAAAAD0/JSy7bmMQm7Q/s1600/eyelashes%2Bcleaner.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="eyelashes cleaner" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DuXSluThtqE/VogGqv0KHBI/AAAAAAAAAD0/JSy7bmMQm7Q/s1600/eyelashes%2Bcleaner.jpg" title=""></a></div>
<br></div>
</span>

<span class="content6" style="display:none">
<div class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in;">
<h3>
<span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: large;"><span style="line-height: 115%;">Tip:6&nbsp;</span><span style="line-height: 18.4px;">Use Light Shade Pencil</span></span></h3>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;">Use
light shade pencil to give more freshness and vigor to your eyes.</span><br>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kb1lAlxKnfA/VogG7Nu43YI/AAAAAAAAAD8/tJmBrrpjFXA/s1600/eye%2Bpencil.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="eye pencil" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kb1lAlxKnfA/VogG7Nu43YI/AAAAAAAAAD8/tJmBrrpjFXA/s1600/eye%2Bpencil.jpg" title=""></a></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<br></div>


<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
If you like this post, don't forget to share these makeup tips with your friends!!!</div>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; font-size: 12.0pt; line-height: 115%;"><br></span></div>
</span>

<p><b>Pages: <span style="color: #3d85c6">
<a href="#" class="page1">1</a>
<a href="#" class="page2">2</a>
<a href="#" class="page3">3</a>
<a href="#" class="page4">4</a>
<a href="#" class="page5">5</a>
<a href="#" class="page6">6</a></span></b></p>
<p></p>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's at the link he posted: http://www.hackinguniversity.in/2015/05/split-blogger-post-add-pages.html

Comment: you mean to say content1 is being displayed on all the pages even though you are trying to hide the content using jquery?

Comment: gotcha!! Issue is the content which you are placing in "content1" span is not inside the span, somehow, it is outside the "content1" span. Try to place it inside the span then it should work as expected.

Comment: @PradeepPotnuru I just have Edited my question, please have a look there I am using JQuery to hide contents

Comment: @MustafaGaziani - the jquery code which you added is perfectly correct. The only issue i see is that when it is being parsed by wordpress it's misplacing the contents.all the tags in content1 is being shifted outside.That is the reason for weird behavior.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity - yes that is what MustafaGaziani is looking for. But, the issue is when he keep the code in wordpress/blogger then the code is some how parsed differently by the blogger.

Comment: @PradeepPotnuru Yes Exactly when I am running my code in IDE its working perfectly might be the issue would be of blogger. Thanks

Comment: Let us know if you find some solution. As a quick fix i can suggest you give the same 'content1' class for all elements in the content1 . This should fix the issue temporarly untill u find the route cause

Comment: Another way is to give dummy 'content0' span which will not have any content and place it as first span. Hope this also fixes your issue.

Comment: @PradeepPotnuru Got the Solution. MiCreativity did great work solving my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first section to be hidden as well, change this:

```
<span class="content1">
Add your first page content here
</span>
<span class="content2" style="display:none">
Add your second page content here
</span>
<span class="content3" style="display:none">
Add your third page content here
</span>
<span class="content4" style="display:none">
Add your final page content here
</span>
```

to this:

```
<span class="content1" style="display:none">
Add your first page content here
</span>
<span class="content2" style="display:none">
Add your second page content here
</span>
<span class="content3" style="display:none">
Add your third page content here
</span>
<span class="content4" style="display:none">
Add your final page content here
</span>
```

The navigation buttons should then work as you expect.

Comment: Its also not working, and if I use style="display:none" then the content1 will also hide but its not happening here.